# Did Windows 10 update remove IIS?

Tags: iis, windows-10, windows-update

For about 5 years now I had a set up on my machine that runs my site locally. I enabled IIS. Configured PHP and MySql to run. Everything was working without an issue.

Today I turned on my PC and got a message that my Windows 10 machine was updated. When I went to check out my localhost, I saw that it wasn't running. IIS was disabled and all of the configurations were gone.

Looking at Windows Update history I see the following updates

[image]

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3189866

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3176937

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3176935

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2504637

Does anyone have an explanation for this? Why did Microsoft disabled IIS and removed all of my configurations? Is there a way to restore my previous settings?

**update:** For now, I rolled back to my previous Window's build and everything is back to normal.

Comment: Our dev team are also experiencing this today too. Some forum posts are also stating that their .Net 2, 3.5 instances have also been removed. Unfortunately I haven't found any resolutions - but you're not alone.

Comment: The immediate answer is to go into Control Panel, Windows Programs & Features and turn on the IIS feature to have it installed again.

Comment: this is the wrong forum for this question

Comment: This is probably better off over in super user, true. Any easy way to move it over there? Because this question needs to be around, somewhere. The same thing happened to me, and knowing that this was an issue with an update, and not me losing my mind, or something worse, was very helpful.

Comment: I can also confirm that this happened to me. Able to reinstall but I have to set up all my sites again and URL rewriting.

Answer (score 3):

Even after I re-enabled IIS, all the sites and app pools were gone.

I explained how I restored them here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184735/270348

Here's the main idea:

1. In a text editor, open `C:\Windows.old\WINDOWS\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config`. This is the original IIS data from before the update.
2. In another text editor open `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config`. This is the active IIS data.
3. Replace the `<applicationPools>` and `<sites>` elements in the active file with those from the original
4. Run `iisreset` from an elevated command prompt

Comment: This worked I made a backup of the current applicationHost.config to the desktop then copied the old one and pasted it over the current one saved and did an iis reset all seems well. Thanks for the post!

Answer (score 0):

Not removed, just not on by default.
Enable it via Control Panel > Windows Programs and Features.

Comment: But there are many reports over the internet saying IIS was removed. Not enough info to confirm though.