# IIS gone (including sites and application pools) after Windows 10 Creators Update

Tags: iis, windows-10, windows-update

After installing the Windows 10 Creators Update (1607), IIS is no longer installed.

When I re-install it from "Turn Windows features on or off", I find that all my application pools and all my sites are gone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "good" news is that there seems to be a way to restore the IIS app pools and sites (after re-enabling IIS from "Turn Windows features on or off").

It’s a little tricky and error prone, but it’s better than nothing.

Here is the procedure that worked for me:

1. In a text editor, open `C:\Windows.old\WINDOWS\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config`. This is the original IIS data from before the update.
2. In another text editor open `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config`. This is the active IIS data.
3. Replace the `<applicationPools>` and `<sites>` elements in the active file with those from the original
4. Run `iisreset` from an elevated command prompt

Comment: This solution didn't completely work for me. The application pool stops and the event log shows, The Module DLL C:\WINDOWS\System32\inetsrv\defdoc.dll failed to load.  The data is the error.

Comment: I copied the administration.config and applicationHost.config files from the C:\Windows.old\WINDOWS\System32\inetsrv\config\ to C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\  and it all started working like a charm.